# Sum in different structures gives the same result MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

At the moment

```
if(sum(row1)>sum(row2) ,sum(row1)-sum(row2),0)
```

gives the same value as

```
sum(if(row1>row2 ,row1-row2,0))
```

Both `grouped by ID`

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - it would be great if you could have a very explicit question, and steps to reproduct, e.g. a sample schema and data.

Comment: Those expressions are not equivalent. For specific data samples they could produce the same result, but most likely they won't. Please add some sample data.